# Understand assign behaviour in pandas using lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a simple pandas dataframe using python 3.8.5 and pandas version 1.2.1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,2], 'y' : [3,4]})
```

I would like to perform a string addition of the 2 columns into the third using assign function.

```
df.assign(c = lambda d: str(d['x']) + str(d['y']))
```

[image]

I was expecting to see the column 'c' to have ['13', '24']

Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `str(d['x'])` you'll get string representation of `pd.Series` ( similar when you do `print(df['x'])` ), which isn't what you want.

If you want use `.assign` with lambda, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2], "y": [3, 4]})

print(df.assign(c=lambda d: d["x"].astype(str) + d["y"].astype(str)))
```

Prints:

```
   x  y   c
0  1  3  13
1  2  4  24
```

Comment: Or in this case just drop the lambda and work in `df` directly

Comment: @Andrej , your suggestion has solved my issue and I have accepted your answer. However, I also like to understand why this is happening.  For instance, if I try the following ```str(df.iloc[1]['x']) + str(df.iloc[1]['y'])``` I get '24' as the answer, I thought lambda function within assign works one row at a time and should work similar to the iloc observation.

Comment: @SrivatsaSrinath lambda in assign doesn't work one row at the time. The argument `d` you've received is simply the dataframe. If you want it for row-by-row basis, you can use `.apply`, for example: `df["c"] = df.apply(lambda d: str(d["x"]) + str(d["y"]), axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, and lucid explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the advices from Andrej and Juanpa above, I tried dropping lambda in the code, and it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2], "y": [3, 4]})
df.assign(c=df.x.astype(str) + df.y.astype(str))
>>>
   x  y   c
0  1  3  13
1  2  4  24
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34915715)

Comment: Since Juanpa did not put any code, and the comments that follow still talking about using lambda, and I find I could simplify the statement further; so I thought I would just materialize their inputs into code. Just voted up as you suggested.